# Suppress WARN statement from console in Grunt uglifyjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs

When I run grunt uglify in my project, I always get warning like this in console:

```
WARN: Dropping unused function o [js/shadowbox.js:8,9661]
WARN: Dropping unused function argument aW [js/shadowbox.js:17,5440]
File "js/bundle/front.bundle.js" created.
```

My uglify option is as followed(compress is true):

```
options: {

                beautify: false, 
                compress: true,
                warnings: false

            },
```

Is there any way to suppress these warnings?

Comment: Did you manage to figure something out for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
options: {
    compress: {
        warnings: false
    }
}
```

Rather than this:

```
options: {
    compress: true
}
```